# iOS - JSON Parsing error (blank logs)

Tags: ios, json

Good day!

I'm having trouble parsing JSON in my ios app. I'm following this tutorial [Click Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MEnvlqP-wU)

This is my connectionDidFinishLoading code

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *arrayOfArray = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"array"];

    for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfArray) {
        NSDictionary *zero = [diction objectForKey:@"0"];
        NSString *foods = [zero objectForKey:@"foods"];

        [array addObject:foods];
   }



    [[self myTableView]reloadData];
     NSLog(@"%@",array);
}
```

The problem is, i don't have anything on my logs, its just

```
2015-01-14 11:19:51.992 NINETEEN[10299:246999] (
)
```

And also, this is my JSON File

```
[
{"id":"1",
"foods":"Baby Back Ribs",
"category":"Main",
"price":"P250",
"image_code":"0"},

{"id":"2",
"foods":"Bacon and Blue Cheese Burger",
"category":"Appetizer",
"price":"P300",
"image_code":"768"},

{"id":"3","foods":
"Frutti de Mare Pasta",
"category":"Pasta",
"price":"P180",
"image_code":"1536"}]
```

And this is it in JSON Viewer http://oi62.tinypic.com/zh36.jpg

Hope you can help me out, thanks!

Comment: Here is a major problem: `error:nil`

Comment: What should i put in error:nil?

Comment: You should use the error parm the way you're supposed to, and the way that trustworthy examples show you.  (And any example that codes `error:nil` is not trustworthy.)

Comment: `NSError *error = nil`, then in the method, `error:&error`. Put a breakpoint after that line to see what error comes back and if `allDataDictionary` is nil.  But just from looking at your JSON, the top element is an array, not a dictionary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
NSArray *arrayOfArray = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"array"];
```

Your JSON document does not contain an element named `array`, so `arrayOfArray` is nil.